# How to convert a dictionary of list into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
new_data = {'mid':mids, 'human':all_tags, 'new':new_tags, 'old':old_tags}
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data.items(), columns=['mid', 'human', 'new', 'old'])
```

new_data is a dictionary, in which the value of each column is a list with equal length. I tried to convert it into a df, but it gives this error:

```
ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
```

How to convert this new_data into a df?

Comment: what's wrong with just `pd.DataFrame(new_data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.items()`:

```py
new_data = {'mid':[1, 2], 'human':[1, 2], 'new':[1, 2], 'old':[1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['mid', 'human', 'new', 'old'])
```

> **Note:**
>
> Passing `columns` here is redundant, because their names equal the dictionary keys anyways. So just use:
>
> ```py
> >>> pd.DataFrame(new_data)
>
>    mid  human  new  old
> 0    1      1    1    1
> 1    2      2    2    2
> ```

---

#### The reason behind the error:

If you try this, here is what you'll get:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(new_data.items())

       0       1
0    mid  [1, 2]
1  human  [1, 2]
2    new  [1, 2]
3    old  [1, 2]
```

Why?

Check this:

```py
>>> list(new_data.items())

[('mid', [1, 2]), ('human', [1, 2]), ('new', [1, 2]), ('old', [1, 2])]
```

It is in a format "list of lists" (well, list of tuples in this case). If `pd.DataFrame()` receives this, it will assume you are going row by row. This is why it constructs only two columns. And that is why your assignment of column names fails - there are 2 columns but you are providing 4 column names.

Comment: Or just `pd.DataFrame(new_data)` because the dictionary keys define the columns by default.